# Looking for help calculating expectation of a “modified” geometric distribution - 3 bit signals

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

hey everyone I was hoping I could get a hint about how to solve the following question - it’s a previous years test question so I only have the final answer

> **The Question**:
>
>  3 bit signals are transmitted through a noisy signal that flips every bit $(1 \to 0 \ ,0 \to 1)$ with a probability of 1/3, independent of the other bits. What’s the expectation of the number of *signals* transmitted wholly transmitted before the first one with a flipped bit

My Thought process is this:
I wanted to define two indicator series: $X =$ the number of bits unflipped.
$$X = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i \quad X_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{the ith bit hasn’t flipped nor have the j<i bits.} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and $Y=$ the number of signals that have been transmitted - what I need to find.
$$Y = \left\lfloor \frac{X}{3} \right\rfloor$$
$$E(Y) = E(E(Y|X)) = E(E(\lfloor X/3 \rfloor |X))$$
I hit a snag trying to calculate this.
is this the best approach or even a correct one? if it is how do I deal with the resulting sum? how would you do it instead?
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \left\lfloor \frac{i}{3} \right\rfloor \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{i-1}$$
I know that once I find this sum the question is easy since I know $E(X)$ from $X \sim \text{Geom}(1/3)$

Comment: the final answer is 8/19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of a signal getting transmitted correctly is $(2/3)^3 = 8/27$. What is asked can be calculated by thinking of it as a geometric random variable with $p = 1-8/27 = 19/27$. Thus, the expected value of the number of signals transmitted correctly is $(1-p)/p = 8/19$.

If you want to do it your way, then note that the sum should instead be

$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{i}{3}\right\rfloor\left(\frac23\right)^i &= \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^2 \left\lfloor\frac{3n+k}{3}\right\rfloor\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3n+k}\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3n}\left(1+\frac{2}{3}+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2\right)\\
&= \frac{19}{27}\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\left(\frac{8}{27}\right)^n\\
&= \frac{8}{19}.
\end{align*}$

You can evaluate the last sum by differentiating the geometric series.

Comment: In the longer calculation can you please explain why you took (2/3) to the power of i as opposed of to the power of 1-i?

Comment: @Lonimous You can check that by letting i=3, so that one signal has been transmitted correctly. This means that 3 bits were not flipped ((2/3)^i), and then one was flipped (1/3). What you had written would count 1 signal when 2 bits were not flipped and the third one was.

Comment: I think you and I have differing definitions of geometric- I’m used to it being the total amount of tries for a success while you consider it the number of failures. so what you did would lead to the direct result while setting up the i index like i originally thought and then removing 1 from the sum will do the trick too, right? anyways I see your point, thanks!